# How to edit the product images in zen cart?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zen-cart

I hate how it just shows each image and have to click each image to show the enlarged display.

Anyway I can re-organize them and/or use a jquery gallery type plugin to go through the different product images?

Something like the effect here would be perfect for the product images
http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/fancy-thumbnail-hover-effect-w-jquery/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a client-side only solution, you could take a look at the pages (home, specials, new products, category listing and product info), and see if there is any css hook for the images that you can use to attach a jquery event to it.

Once found, you can use, as you suggest, a jquery image plugin to do the job of enlarging/slideshow etc. If you are interested in this jquery solution I can explain it further, I made it a few times with different templates. You will (depending on your needs) proably need to modify or add some php anyway.

If you prefer or need to modify the PHP output, you will have to modify a few template files, located as you probably know in /includes/templates/my-template-name/. If you only want to deal with the product_info image/s, it is much easier. You only need to edit the my-template-name/templates/tpl_product_info_default.php file. Again, I will explain further if you need, but I would probably need to see your templates tpl_product_info_default file to be able to help you further.